# Undefined index php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ){ can't find answer?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

```
    <form class="login" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="POST">
    <h4 class="text-center">Admin Login</h4>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="user" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="off"/>
    <input class="form-control" type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="new-password"/>
    <input class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit"  value="Login">
  </form>
```

I made form `method="POST"` on `php`

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ){

  $username =   $_POST['user'];
  $pass =       $_POST['pass'];
  $hashPass =   sha1($pass);

  $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT Username,Password FROM users WHERE Username = ? AND Password = ?");
  $stmt->execute(array($username,$hashPass));
  $count =$stmt->rowCount();

  echo $count;
```

but result

> Notice: Undefined index: user in C:\xampp\htdocs\eCommerc\admin\index.php on line 7
>
> Notice: Undefined index: pass in C:\xampp\htdocs\eCommerc\admin\index.php on line 8

Comment: do you have a closing form tag? after your last <input> tag?

Comment: you are getting this error on page load or  on form submit?

Comment: As you can see from the comments - people need some more information from you than just the code and your errors. I suggest visiting [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to get a better insight on how to ask a solid question. A slightly better explanation is necessary in order for others to offer you help (they 1st need to understand what the actual issue is). Hang in there. You'll be great at this. ;)

Comment: @Juakali92 Yes did it , and no errors At phpstorm

Comment: @vivekmodi from (form submit) :(

Comment: Are both php code and html form in the same page?

Comment: @NadunKulatunge yes in the same page

Answer (score 0):

This problem because the Windows Operation system doesn't Enable some PHP

method to be sure use phpinfo() function will not find REQUEST_METHOD

so change the Operation system or try to use another method

Comment: It has nothing to do with the operating system, let alone the fact that you don't even know what OS the OP was using...